# Terraform aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm using terraform to provision an elasticbeanstalk environment.  I want redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS. Here is my current configuration:

```
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "env" {
  ...

  # Configure the default listener (port 80) on a classic load balancer.
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elb:listener:80"
    name      = "InstancePort"
    value     = "80"
  }
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elb:listener:80"
    name      = "ListenerEnabled"
    value     = "true"
  }

  # Configure additional listeners on a classic load balancer.
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elb:listener:443"
    name      = "ListenerProtocol"
    value     = "HTTPS"
  }
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elb:listener:443"
    name      = "InstancePort"
    value     = "80"
  }
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elb:listener:443"
    name      = "ListenerEnabled"
    value     = "true"
  }

  # Modify the default stickiness and global load balancer policies for a classic load balancer.
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elb:policies"
    name      = "ConnectionSettingIdleTimeout"
    value     = "60"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elbv2:listener:443"
    name      = "SSLCertificateArns"
    value     = "${aws_acm_certificate.cert.arn}"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elb:listener:443"
    name      = "SSLCertificateId"
    value     = "${aws_acm_certificate.cert.arn}"
  }
```

I've tried various solutions posted online, none will actually work though. Any idea what is wrong with my current configuration? Thanks in advance.

edit: entire config (stackoverflow would not allow posting it all for some reason) https://pastebin.com/aMHgSiXr